# C# - Disassembly of int value

Tags: integer

for already few days I am trying to figure out how to disassembly value by its characters.
Here is example of what I am trying:

```
int a = 159;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
//Magic
//Now b haves value of first digit (b = 1)
//c have value of second digit (c = 5)
//d have value of third digit (d = 9)
```

Thank you ʕっ•ᴥ•ʔっ

Comment: Try modulo arithmetics: `b = a / 100; c = a / 10 % 10; d = a % 10` if `a` is **3** digit number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` is a **3** digits number, e.g.

```
a = 159
```

you can try modulo arithmetics (`/` stands for *integer division*, `%` for *remainder*)

```
b = a / 100;     // 3-d  digit from the end
c = a / 10 % 10; // 2-nd digit from the end
d = a % 10;      // 1-st digit from the end
```

In general case, to get `n`-th digit from the end

```
x = a / 10..00 % 10
         |   |
         n - 1 zeroes
```